# HTML Redirect a link to another link because of 403 error

Tags: html, redirect, http-status-code-403

Ok, so I have a button on my website, that I want to link to a video. It works when I'm viewing the site as a file on my computer; but when I view it on the web, it gives a me a 403 error. I figured this was because I was trying to access the file directly, and the site wanted me to access the file via the page just before the file. So I either need some code that when I push this button, it goes to the page before this file on their server, but then automatically redirects to this file. Or someone could just tell me another way to get past this problem.

Here is the code for the button on my site:

```
<td><a href="http://streaming.isho.ws/HIMM/S7/HIMM.S07E23-24.mp4" class="button_link btn_red"><span>Watch Now</span></a></td>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't get a 403 error, my browser starts downloading an mp4 file. I'm not sure I understand your problem.

Comment: Really?? Did you do anything different? Did you put in a site and view it as a local file, or did you upload it and try it? Because when I viewed it as a local file, it worked. But when I uploaded it to the web and tried to view it from there, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

403 error is returned when the user doesn't have access to the file or media they are trying to access. Check to see what the permissions are on the mp4 you are trying to access and make sure it is accessible.

Comment: I get that I don't have permission. That's why I was gunna try to make their server think I was accessing the file via their server and not mine. Basically, in the end, I need to be able to view that file on my site without it noticeably leaving my site for another one. Any ideas? Maybe you know a way I could download the file and upload it myself?

Comment: If it's not your file and you can't modify the permissions on it pretty much every option left is illegal.

Comment: Yeah, your right. But can you maybe tell me why it won't work like any other link to a site? Actually, I have to sources of vids for my site. That's one, but the other one, I did the same exact way with a different link, and it worked.

Comment: I guess I'm still a little confused on what your problems is but I can say that it's easy to disable access to files based where you are accessing it from. It's used to keep people from downloading or being able to view files outside of the host's site.